# Buildroot Login without Root Password

Tags: password, root, busybox, buildroot

Starting with some of the trunk builds of Buildroot in 2023, I've been unable to login to my buildroot systems with getty.  Honestly, I'd rather a mechanism to just be dumped into a root shell.  But, using getty would be fine.  I just don't want to have to manually edit any files on the FS.  All of my tooling is setup around being able to use buildroot config files.

This is what I am currently trying.

```
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_PORT="console"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_BAUDRATE_KEEP=y
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_BAUDRATE="0"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_TERM="vt100"
BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_OPTIONS="-n -L"
```

But when I try to login as root, I get

```
buildroot login: root
Password:
Login incorrect
Jan  1 00:00:23 login[28]: invalid password for 'root' on 'console'
```

Ultimately I want to avoid having to write in custom `/etc/inittab` rules, like adding the following:

```
console::respawn:/bin/login -f root
```

Because it would be difficult to automatically deploy.

And I want to avoid a custom getty line using `/bin/sh` like `BR2_TARGET_GENERIC_GETTY_OPTIONS="-n -l /bin/sh"` because it doesn't start in `/root`.

Any suggestions/ideas?